# copying file from Finder works with event.clipboardData but not with navigator.clipboard.read()

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I have a form on my HTML page, and I want users to be able to paste images to the form, instead of selecting the file from the upload dialog.

- OS: MacOS
- browser: Chrome

I tried 2 implementations:

1. react to the "paste" event, and read clipboard content from `event.clipboardData.files`
2. react to a "click" event on the button that says "click me to paste", and read clipboard content from `navigator.clipboardData.read()`

Both implementations work when I copy the image within my browser. However, when I try to paste an image copied from Finder, only the `event.clipboardData.files` implementation works.

With implementation 2,

- the type of the clipboard content is `text/plain`
- when I get the content with `navigator.clipboard.readText()`, I see that the content is the name of my file (e.g. `IMG_xxx.jpg`)

Here are the codes for both implementation:

implementation 1

```js
  const preview = document.querySelector('#preview')
  const base64Textarea = document.querySelector('#base64-data')
  const reader = new FileReader()

  // show the image base64 and preview
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    // convert image file to base64 string
    const base64Data = reader.result
    base64Textarea.value = base64Data
    preview.src = base64Data
  }, false)

  window.addEventListener("paste", e => getPastedFiles(e))
  /* handle pasted files */
  const getPastedFiles = event => {
    console.log("paste")
    const input = event.target
    const copiedFiles = event.clipboardData.files
    
    if (!copiedFiles.length) {
      return
    }

    const file = copiedFiles[0]
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)    
  }
```

implementation 2

```js
const pasteImage = async (button) => {
  const tr = button.parentElement.parentElement
  const clipboardItems = await navigator.clipboard.read()

  var image_blob = null
  for (const item of clipboardItems) {
    const image_types = item.types.filter(type => type.split("/")[0] == "image")
    console.log(item.types)
    if (item.types.includes("text/plain")) {
      text_blob = await item.getType("text/plain")
      console.log(text_blob)
      handleUpdateImage(text_blob, tr)
    }
    if (!image_types.length) continue

    image_blob = await item.getType(image_types[0])
  }

  if (!image_blob) return
  handleUpdateImage(image_blob, tr)
}

const handleUpdateImage = async (blob, tr) => {
  const image_base64 = await blobToBase64(blob)
  const preview = tr.querySelector('.preview')
  const hidden = tr.querySelector('[data-field="image_base64"] > input')
  preview.src = image_base64
  hidden.value = image_base64
  if (preview.style.display == 'none') preview.style.display = 'inherit'
}
```

Why does this happen? Is there a limitation on `navigator.clipboard` that does not allow copying file contents from my local machine?